# How to Invert Color on Mac running Catalina?

Tags: color, catalina

I just downloaded the new version of OS, and I found out the shortcut key Ctrl-Opt-Cmd-8 doesn't trigger invert colors anymore. I thought maybe they changed the shortcut, so I tried to search in System Preference but ended with no luck. Did Apple remove invert colors? If not, where can I find it? Is there any shortcut key for it? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comment section with @[user3439894](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/115523/user3439894), we found there're **three** locations on OS Catalina where you can find the settings regarding to Invert Colors.

1) **System Preferences > Accessibility > Display**, use the checkbox to manually activate Invert Colors.

2) **System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Accessibility**, use the checkbox to activate shortcut key Ctrl-Opt-Cmd-8 for Invert Colors. Also, do the following in point 3:

3) **System Preferences > Accessibility > Shortcut**, use the checkbox "Invert Display Color" to use shortcut key Ctrl-Opt-Cmd-8 for Invert Colors.

If you found the checkboxs for shortcut is already checked, but when you press shortcut key and it's not working, try to uncheck and recheck the checkboxs.

Answer (score 4):

I can only use the keyboard shortcut if I go into System Preferences and explicitly unckeck and re-check the box for Invert Colors.  Once I am done with my session I enable screen saver by going to a designated not corner.  When I come back, the keyboard shortcut only produces the system sound for an alert without inverting the colors.  It is again only when I go back into System Preferences and uncheck/re-check Invert Colors will it work again.  This is highly annoying and frustrating as I rely on this for various apps that do not have a dark mode in my normal daily workflow.

Comment: Furthermore, changing the hotkey for that function to ANYTHING that is available still yields the same result.  After returning to the computer, the hotkey no longer works until I go in and un-check and re-check the setting.  This is most definitely a bug in Catalina that needs to be brought up through the channels ASAP for us low vision users to continue to benefit from using macOS.

Comment: I would also like to add that a PRAM reset did not resolve the issue, making this almost without a doubt a bug in Catalina - especially since there was no issue with this in any prior macOS release.  Frustrating to say the least.  Anyone have a channel to get Apple to look into this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. But I found a temporary fix: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to see Accessibility options window, then turn on 'Invert colours'. After that the shortcut will work until next login/screensaver.

I've just reset NVRAM/PRAM and shortcuts seem to work as expected! Finally!
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063