# Using a MacBook Air outsde ☀️ with "Inverted Screen Colors"

Tags: macbook-pro, screen, color, accessibility

I occasionally sit in the garden, under a parasol, and am in very long and boring Teams meetings.
I did a web search on how to see the screen better and found a tip

> Working Outside on Your MacBook Pro? [Invert Your Screen Colors!](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/372398/how-to-invert-color-on-mac-running-catalina)

That was useful, you can really see the screen better.

What does Invert Your Screen Colors do exactly? How does it work? Is it harmful to the eyes? I'm looking for some more background info on this feature. Does it put more strain on the batteries? Are there any other tips for participating in meetings outside in the garden with a Macbook Pro and never-ending Teams calls?

Comment: The mac at one end of the garden and you the other :) I just **love** meetings... Sorry couldn't resist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What does Invert Your Screen Colors do exactly?**

Each color on your screen is represented by a number. You may have seen colors in web pages represented as FFEE03: this is a hexadecimal (base 16) number, where Red, Green and Blue values are described by each pair of numbers. Black is 0, and White is FFFFFF (in decimal, 16,777,215). By 'flipping' the numbers to their opposite value in the range, the colors take on their 'complementary' hue.

[image]

So, in the image, all the sliders are set to the middle (grey). You can see how moving any of the sliders one side or the other will affect the color.

**How does it work?**
Maths. Everything in a computer is represented by a number, and its very easy to transform those numbers into something else. That's what makes computers so useful. The computer is just sending the display controller different numbers.

**Is it harmful to the eyes?**
Not necessarily. But brighter images, viewed for longer, will be more tiring.

**Does it put more strain on the batteries?**
Battery life is unaffected.